# Parse image from json api

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to work with the Dog API, trying to get a random breed image and display it in a ListTile

Model class

```
class DogData {
  DogData ({this.message, this.status});
  String message;
  String status;

  factory DogData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DogData (
    message: json["message"],
    status: json["status"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "message": message,
    "status": status,
  };
}
```

There is an error inside the ListTile, undefined name "index". Where did I go wrong and how can I fix it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practice_5/model/breedModel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
class BreedListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<List<DogData>> fetchDogs(http.Client client) async {
    final response = await client.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random');
    return compute(parseDog, response.body);
  }
  List<DogData> parseDog(responseBody) {
    final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody) as List;
    return parsed.map<DogData>((json) => DogData.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
  BreedListTile({Key key, List<DogData> dogList})
      : _dogList = dogList,
        super(key: key);
  final List<DogData> _dogList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text('Test title'),
        subtitle: Text('Test subtitle'),
        leading: Container(
          child: Image.asset(_dogList[index].message),
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your `ListTile`'s under a `ListView` widget. Try something like this:

```
ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: _dogList.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text('Test title'),
        subtitle: Text('Test subtitle'),
        leading: Container(
          child: Image.network(_dogList[index].message),
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    )
```

**Edit:**

By the way, you are trying to get an image from a URL. So, you need to use `Image.network('url')`. Read [more](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image).

Comment: For some reason _dogList.length = null